# Flutter Unable to merge dex

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using last version of flutter.

**Error :**

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUİLD FAILED in 3s
Finished with error: Gradle build failed: 1
```

pubspec.yaml dependencies, using firebase_auth ^0.5.20 :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  intl: ^0.15.7
  cloud_firestore: ^0.7.3
  firebase_database: ^1.0.4
  cached_network_image: ^0.4.2
  firebase_auth: ^0.5.20
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
```

android app build.gradle default config:

```
android{
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.flutterapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

Comment: try flutter clean first

Answer (score 6):

Try adding the dependency as well

```
...
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
  }
  ...
}
...
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' // use latest version
  ...
}
...
```

See also

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20747#issuecomment-414126225
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21009